# PocketSphinx output nothing

Tags: cmusphinx

I want to do a Chinese speech recognition application. I build a language model（using CMUCLMTK） and an acoustic model base on the tutorial

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam

But I got nothing output while using the

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -hmm ... -lm ... -dict ...
```

The output just like

```
READY....
Listening...
Recoding is stopped, start...
Stoped listening...
...(lots of INFO)
000000000:(nothing here!)
READY....
```

I've checked my wav files' format, it's 16it 16KHz mono.
And also use `./scripts_pl/decode/slave.pl` command and the result is 40% Error rate.(My model and training set is very small). 
My devices are running well because I've test pocketSphinx in English model and it performs very well.

**What other may lead to that strange result?**

Answer (score 0):

> What other may lead to that strange result?

It's impossible to answer your question because you didn't provide the data files you are using. The troubleshooting section of the tutorial says

> If you want to ask for help about training, **try to provide the
>   training folder** or at least logdir folder. We would be glad to help you.

Comment: Thank you! I'v solved it. Just because there's something wrong with my dict file.